# When can the Sun, Moon and the five naked-eye planets all be in Leo?

Tags: observational-astronomy

What are the possible dates for the seven (classical/mediaeval) planets (Sun, Moon, Mars, Mercury, Jupiter, Saturn, Venus) all being in Leo?

I’m not sure how to figure this out on my own. I’m interested in this for the purposes of historical dating. Example: the planetary positions are recorded in art. These positions are only possible every so often and I’d like to know the possibilities.

Here’s one of the example. This is called the Metternich Stele, named after the Prince who received it shortly after its discovery. [image: The original]

Here’s the first drawing of it by the Russian Egyptologist V. S. Golenishchev. [image: VSG’s Drawing]

The full analysis of this zodiac can be read in Russian @ http://chronologia.org/zodiaki_eg_eu/z1_02.html

Comment: Do you mean the astrological sign Leo, or the constellation Leo as defined by the International Astronomical Union?

Comment: We prefer not to believe the Sun is a planet...

Comment: @barrycarter the sign

Comment: @JamesK this is a question of spherical astronomy, not astrology.

Comment: Your motive isn't my concern, but to keep this question open for answers, you'll need to [revise it](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/posts/34753/edit) in terms that don't trigger astrology haters.

Comment: Also see [Finding Quintuple Planetary Alignments with SkyField](/q/34333)

Comment: My answer to https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19301/period-of-unique-horoscopes should answer this question as well. You could argue the Sun is a planet in the sense of "wanderer" (from which planet is derived) since it changes constellations unlike the fixed stars.

Comment: @Trip I only slightly disagree with Carl Witthoft. I didn't think it is a matter of belief of what the sun is, I thought it was a matter of definition.  I don't think this is the place for archaic definitions, calling the sun a wanderer.  I think it would be best to go by the agreed upon definitions used by this SE. Using an archaic astrological definition in this question I'm voting to close.

Comment: Trip, I think the community here would be more forgiving if you could provide a rationale for you wanting to know these dates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Period of unique horoscopes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19301/period-of-unique-horoscopes)

Comment: @Hug I updated it

Comment: @PM2Ring, good idea. There’s currently three of which I’m aware.

Comment: @PM2Ring I accidentally hit send. The first one can be found in the Tomb of Senenmut. All classical planets are in Leo. The second one is the Metternich Stele. The third one is the Mithras Zodiac. I’d share picture here but I’m not sure if thats possible. I’m interested in this for purely astronomical and historical reasons. I could care less what astrologers think about this

Comment: @PM2Ring Here’s the full list of dates I’d like to verify. I just picked the ones all in Leo because I figured they’d be the easiest to determine - https://ctruth.today/2019/01/18/new-chronology-zodiac-list/

Comment: @PM2Ring sweet ty

Answer (score 2):

I created the house-states.txt.bz2 file in https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/ASTRO/ to answer [Period of unique horoscopes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19301/period-of-unique-horoscopes) and, according to this file, all 7 "planets" are in Leo during the following times:

- BCE 3440-SEP-01 01:14 to BCE 3440-SEP-01 05:19
- BCE 1437-AUG-25 19:38 to BCE 1437-AUG-28 08:36
- CE 5156-JUL-25 10:49 to CE 5156-JUL-26 20:26
- CE 5773-JUL-19 10:22 to CE 5773-JUL-21 17:27
- CE 7125-AUG-18 14:08 to CE 7125-AUG-18 21:25
- CE 10362-JUL-19 06:08 to CE 10362-JUL-21 11:14
- CE 11891-AUG-12 22:08 to CE 11891-AUG-13 07:44
- CE 14334-JUL-26 00:49 to CE 14334-JUL-28 13:30

The file covers the time frame BCE 13201-AUG-16 to CE 17191-FEB-28.

Below is a Stellarium image of when all the planets are in Leo in 5156. Note:

- Even though the astrological sign is Leo (between 120 and 150 degrees in the ecliptic grid), precession means the planets are actually in Taurus and Gemini
- The Stellarium timestamp, 5156-07-25 02:02:18, falls outside the time range I give above, I'm not sure why.

[image]

Comment: Is precession the reason why they dont recur at similar intervals? 3440BC to 1437BC is a lot more time than 5156AD to 5773AD. What would the results look like without adding the precession variable?