# How to calculate planetary positions hundreds or thousands of years ago

Tags: amateur-observing, positional-astronomy, equinox, solstice

Wondering how to calculate the following in a general way:

- Sunrise/sunset
- Equinoxes/solstices
- Moon phases
- Planetary positions

For hundreds to thousands of years ago. Wondering what the calculation is, or where I go about figuring it out.

I would like to be able to say, in 1541 on Jan 1 the sun rose at x time, Jupiter was in y position, etc.

Comment: If you seriously want to do this from scratch, take a look at *Astronomical Algorithms* by Jean Meeus. Otherwise, learn Python and use [Astropy](https://www.astropy.org/about.html). In either case, be prepared to devote some time to learning the necessary background information.

Comment: For Python you can also use [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) since it is based on pre-calculated ephemerides provided by NASA/JPL. WIth a few lines of Python you can calculate all kinds of conjunctions and positions in the sky.

Comment: I think there should be a good answer to this question [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/13009/7982) **and especially [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/13489/7982).**